# Move origin of all objects to same Y value

Tags: origin

I am making a Font in Blender. I have modeled it as OBJ files for my 3D Rendering Engine, however I discovered the centers are all incorrect... the origins are at the origin of the world i modeled them in. So I centered all their centers to center of mass. Now, the centers are overall in the centers lines of the shapes. That's good, but now I want to set all their origins to be at the same Y value, preferably 0. Is there a way I can do that?

**MY QUESTION**
I want to set the origins of all objects to the same Y value without altering their X or Z values

if I could write a script to do it, I'd love to, although I've never written in python before, so I'd need to know for instance how to loop through all objects in the scene and how to access and set their origin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy this script into your scripting window and press "Run Script"

```
import bpy 

for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    obj.location.y = 0
```

Good night.